# How to enable zoom in Cordova iOS app

Tags: javascript, raphael, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I have a web app I've run through Cordova/PhoneGap to create an iOS app.  When I run the site on mobile Safari, zooming in and out works fine, but on the iPhone and iPad pinch to zoom doesn't work anymore.

Is there something in Cordova that would be preventing normal zooming from working?

The app uses the RaphaelJS plugin but that's all, aside from the cordova js library

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: EnableViewportScale]

you need to enable the ViewportScale in the Cordova.plist, which is set to NO by default.